# Does the sed command just append text inline to the first line?

Tags: bash, sed

I am going through a setup script that I am attempting to understand; how the sed line works, in this instance. From my understanding, it is editing the `src/conf-cc` inline at the first line and appending `-include /usr/include/errno.h/` to the last line of input? I have been referencing the sed manual to help me break this sed command down.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# A script which installs daemontools
#
# Run as root!
#

if [ "$(id -u)" != "0" ]; then
   echo "You must be root!" 1>&2
   exit 1
fi

mkdir /package
chmod 1755 /package
cd /package
wget http://cr.yp.to/daemontools/daemontools-0.76.tar.gz
tar -xpf daemontools-0.76.tar.gz
rm -f daemontools-0.76.tar.gz
cd admin/daemontools-0.76
sed -i '1s/$/ -include \/usr\/include\/errno.h/' src/conf-cc
package/install
echo -e "start on runlevel [3] \nrespawn \nexec /command/svscanboot" >> /etc/init/svscan.conf

initctl reload-configuration
initctl start svscan

mkdir /var/svc.d
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it just appends something to the first line. It's a substitution command:

```
addr s/pattern/replacement/
```

where *`addr`* is `1` (first line), *`pattern`* is `$` (regex: end of line) and the *`replacement`* is the  `-include ...` string. It's not really "replacing" anything as `$` has zero width anyway.

Your misunderstanding is interpreting `$` as an address instead of a regular expression.

Comment: Ah, it makes much more sense with that substitution command and your explanation! Thank you very much @benjamin-w!